# How to register only once in react useEffect and get useState changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react hook component which needs to register to an outside event as follows:

```js
const DefaultRateSection: React.FC<{
    registerOnSaveEvent: (fn: () => void) => void;
  }> = ({registerOnSaveEvent}) => {
    const [serviceName, setServiceName] = useState('the name');
    const serviceNameInput = useRef<input>(null);
    
    useEffect(
      () => {
        return registerOnSaveEvent(() => {
          if (!serviceName) {
            serviceNameInput.current?.focus();
          }
        });
      },
      [registerOnSaveEvent]
    );
    return (
        <input
        ref={serviceNameInput}
        value={serviceName}
        onChange={(event) => {
            const newValue = event.target.value;
            setServiceName(newValue)
        }}
        />
    );
  };
```

The `registerOnSaveEvent` is an API that i cannot change and i do not have an unsubscribe method, therefore i need to register to it only once. However, when it fires (from outside the component) i'm receiving the initial value of `serviceName` and not the updated one. I know it happens because i'm not calling `useEffect` after the change, but I need to avoid multiple registrations.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL-TR: The short answer is to use another ref so that the arrow function can access the latest rendered value of service name.

```
const serviceNameRef = useRef();
serviceNameRef.current = serviceName; 
// use serviceNameRef.current in the arrow function
```

---

## This code will NOT work

```js
// Get a hook function - only needed for this Stack Snippet
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;


const DefaultRateSection = ({ registerOnSaveEvent }) => {
  const [serviceName, setServiceName] = useState("the name");
  const serviceNameInput = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return registerOnSaveEvent(() => {
      console.log(serviceName)
    });
  }, [registerOnSaveEvent]);
  
  return (
    <input
      ref={serviceNameInput}
      value={serviceName}
      onChange={(event) => {
        const newValue = event.target.value;
        setServiceName(newValue);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const callbackRef = useRef();
  
  function registerOnSaveEvent(callback) {
    callbackRef.current=callback
  }
  
  function execCallback() {
    callbackRef.current();
  }

  return <div>
    <h2>This will not work</h2>
    <p>Try to change the input field and click 'RegisterOnSaveEvent'.</p>
    <p>The callback will not see the new value of the input</p>
    <DefaultRateSection registerOnSaveEvent={registerOnSaveEvent}/>
    <button onClick={execCallback}>RegisterOnSaveEvent</button>
  </div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

## This code will work

```js
// Get a hook function - only needed for this Stack Snippet
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;


const DefaultRateSection = ({ registerOnSaveEvent }) => {
  const [serviceName, setServiceName] = useState("the name");
  const serviceNameInput = useRef();

  // use a ref for the service name and
  // update it with the serviceName state on every render
  const serviceNameRef = useRef();
  serviceNameRef.current = serviceName;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    return registerOnSaveEvent(() => {
      console.log(serviceNameRef.current)
    });
  }, [registerOnSaveEvent]);
  
  return (
    <input
      ref={serviceNameInput}
      value={serviceName}
      onChange={(event) => {
        const newValue = event.target.value;
        setServiceName(newValue);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const callbackRef = useRef();
  
  function registerOnSaveEvent(callback) {
    callbackRef.current=callback
  }
  
  function execCallback() {
    callbackRef.current();
  }

  return <div>
    <h2>This will work</h2>
    <p>Try to change the input field and click 'RegisterOnSaveEvent'.</p>
    <p>The callback will not see the new value of the input</p>
    <DefaultRateSection registerOnSaveEvent={registerOnSaveEvent}/>
    <button onClick={execCallback}>RegisterOnSaveEvent</button>
  </div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

## Explanation

When the `useEffect` is executed it creates an arrow function. This arrow function references the const `serviceName` which is the initial value. This is the value that the arrow function sees. When you enter something in the input field you call the `setServiceName` which changes the state and triggers a rerender. The rendering itself is nothing but a function call. So when the component is rerendered the `useState` returns the state and you assign it to a brand new local const named `serviceName`. This is NOT the same as the one that the arrow function references. Thus the arrow function will always see the value of `serviceName` when it was created.

To solve this problem I use another ref for the `serviceName` called `serviceNameRef` and update that ref with the `serviceName` state on every rendering. Since `useRef` returns the same instance of `serviceRefName` on each call, it is the same instance as the one the arrow function uses. That's how it works.